# django dynamic scraper range_funct pagination

Tags: django, pagination, range, django-dynamic-scraper

I am using [`django-dynamic-scraper`](https://github.com/holgerd77/django-dynamic-scraper) in one of my applications, I have gone through the [docs](http://django-dynamic-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced_topics.html#pagination) and following is my setup:

object class url I am using is : `http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products.html`

The pagination on the site is something like the following.

page 1: `http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products.html`
page 2: `http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products2.html`
page 3: `http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products3.html`
page 4: `http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products4.html`

The `brandname` in the above urls is dynamic and depends on a brand's products page. I cannot have a different scraper for each brand as there are over 10000 brands so I am trying to use a single scraper object.

In the scraper object that I am using I have defined the pagination options as follows:

`pagination_type`: `RANGE_FUNCT`
`pagination_append_str`: `_products{page}.html`
`pagination_page_replace`: `1,100,2`

but the scraper requests the following pagination urls

`http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products.html_products2.html`
`http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products.html_products3.html`
`http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products.html_products4.html`

Instead of

`http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products2.html`
`http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products3.html`
`http://www.example.com/products/brandname_products4.html`

Q: Why is it appending the replace string to the end of the url instead of actually replacing it with `_products.html` in the object class url ? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pagination_append_str` option is called like this, because the string is *appended* to the base url and not replacing it! :-)

So everything is correct, you just have to remove `_products_html` from your base url so that the final url is build together without doubling url parts.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah figured that out the other day

Comment: @Amyth then would it not be appropriate to accept his answer?